# useEffect, overwrites the if statement

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to sort a list by ordering with an object value, but with `useState`, the if statements only triggers in if statement but not both `if` and `else` :

```
const { countryList } = useCustomerData();
useEffect(()=>{
    if(type === 'nationality'){
      countryList.sort((a: CountryObject, b: CountryObject) =>
        a.nationality.localeCompare(b.nationality))
    }else {
      countryList.sort((a: CountryObject, b: CountryObject) =>
        a.country.localeCompare(b.country))
    }
  }, [countryList, type])
```

This is countryList :

```
[{country: 'Afghanistan', code: 'AF', prefix: '93', nationality: 'Afghan'}
1: {country: 'Ägypten', code: 'EG', prefix: '20', nationality: 'Egyptian'}
2: {country: 'Åland-Inseln', code: 'AX', prefix: '+358-18', nationality: 'Åland-Inseln'}
3: {country: 'Albanien', code: 'AL', prefix: '355', nationality: 'Albanisch'}
4: {country: 'Algerien', code: 'DZ', prefix: '213', nationality: 'Algerian'}]
```

The list is very long but that's the sample list.

MY SECOND ATTEMPT :

```
const [countryFinal, setCountryFinal] = useState<CountryType[]>([])


  const value = useMemo(() => _get(values, name), [values, name]);

  useEffect(()=>{
    if(type === 'nationality'){
      setCountryFinal(countryList.sort((a: CountryObject, b: CountryObject) =>
        a.nationality.localeCompare(b.nationality)))
    }else {
      setCountryFinal(countryList.sort((a: CountryObject, b: CountryObject) =>
        a.country.localeCompare(b.country)))
    }
  }, [countryList, type, setCountryFinal])
```

This also failed.

for more check out this [code](https://gist.github.com/huxaiphaer/ee8ce0dc244642c13a606bab110335f0)

Comment: Is `countryList` part of your component state? Because if so, you're breaking the fundamental rule of React state: You can't directly modify state values, you have to create a *new* value instead. So: `setCountryList(countryList.slice().sort(/*...*/));`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, I tried something like that but was the same issue , by the way country list is from context :
`const { countryList } = useCustomerData();`

Comment: You can't directly modify context items, either. If you want a sorted version, you'll have to copy it to state and then sort it.

Comment: How do you tell the `else` branch is not triggered? I don’t see pb in this code snippet.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder and , I have modified my code, with the second attempt, but still didn't work. Pardon me on the statement you can't modify direclty items ? I think I did that

Comment: `sort` sorts the array you call it on, which in your case is the one held in state. Your second attempt looks similar to what I was suggesting doing; see my answer for how I'd approach it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've said the country list comes (indirectly) from context. You can't directly modify context items like that. If you want the component to have its own sorted order for that list, you'll have to sort it on each render (probably not ideal) or store a sorted version in state, updating it as necessary.

Something along these lines:

```
const { countryList } = useCustomerData();
const [ sortedCountryList, setSortedCountryList ] = useState<CountryObject[]>([]); // (Or you could init it with `countryList`)

useEffect(()=>{
    if (type === "nationality"){
        setSortedCountryList(countryList.slice().sort((a: CountryObject, b: CountryObject) =>
            a.nationality.localeCompare(b.nationality)
        ));
    } else {
        setSortedCountryList(countryList.slice().sort((a: CountryObject, b: CountryObject) =>
            a.country.localeCompare(b.country)
        ));
    }
}, [countryList, type]); // <=== Update the sorted list when either the context
                         // value or the sort type changes

// ...use `sortedCountryList` for rendering
```